# Strophe retrieving info before entering a room

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I have a web XMPP client, based on Strophe, which connects to a private instance of Openfire server.

After connection to XMPP server I get all public rooms list.

Now I need a way to retrieve some info of those rooms without entering them.

In particular I need the current number of participants and eventually the list of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a `disco#items` query to a MUC room to retrieve the list of current occupants, see [XEP-0045 §6.5](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roomitems).

The user hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda queries the room coven@chat.shakespeare.lit for its list of participants:

```xml
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    id='kl2fax27'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

Room responds:

```xml
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id='kl2fax27'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'>
    <item jid='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/firstwitch'/>
    <item jid='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/secondwitch'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

The server may refuse to answer if this information is private.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know how to do that using Strophe.js

Comment: @vp-platform Add the disco plugin from https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/disco, call `conn.disco.items(...)`.